# HTML menu integration in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

ok. Where to begin with. I have just purchased this nice theme which I am integrating into ASP.NET web forms.

So far so good the theme is working nice, However when I add more pages the menu and the drop down menus are not working.

I have a default.aspx and then when I call another page I see the menu but the menu is not working and the drop down menus are not working too.

What am I missing here? I am using master pages.

Here is the master page code.

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Tutorial1.SiteMaster" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DayPilot" Namespace="DayPilot.Web.Ui" TagPrefix="DayPilot" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PhaseGroup Customer Administration Panel</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.gif">
    <!---CSS Files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tables.css">
    <!---jQuery Files-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/styler.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tipTip.js"></script>
    <script src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sticky.full.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Styles/mGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!---Fonts-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">

        <!--- HEADER -->

        <div class="header">
            <a href="dashboard.html">
                <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
            <div class="styler">
                <ul class="styler-show">
                    <li>
                        <div id="colorSelector-top-bar"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div id="colorSelector-box-head"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="top-bar">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li id="user-panel">
                    <img src="../img/nav/usr-avatar.jpg" id="usr-avatar" alt="" />
                    <div id="usr-info">
                        <p id="usr-name">Welcome back, Michael.</p>
                        <p id="usr-notif">You have 6 notifications. <a href="#">View</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#">Preferences</a><a href="#">Profile</a><a href="index.html">Log out</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul id="top-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="../Products/ProductDetails1.aspx">
                                <img src="img/nav/dash-active.png" alt="" /><p>Dashboard</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="analytics.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/anlt.png" alt="" /><p>Analytics</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="tables.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/tb.png" alt="" /><p>Tables</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="calendar.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/cal.png" alt="" /><p>Calendar</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="widgets.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/widgets.png" alt="" /><p>Widgets</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="grid.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/grid.png" alt="" /><p>Grid</p>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">12 Columns</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">16 Columns</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="filemanager.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/flm.png" alt="" /><p>File Manager</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="gallery.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/gal.png" alt="" /><p>Gallery</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="icons.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/icn.png" alt="" /><p>Icons</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="img/nav/err.png" alt="" /><p>Error Pages</p>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-nav">
                                <li><a href="403.html">403 Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="503.html">503 Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="typography.html">
                                <img src="img/nav/typ.png" alt="" /><p>Typography</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks on the comment. When I run the web site at the default.aspx the menu is working. I get the drop downs or the sub menus but then when I jump to another page lets say default1.aspx the menu is still in there because it is in the master page but then the sub menus are not coming up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, have you checked your debugger on the browser and are there any errors?

You're loading a lot of scripts and jquery stuff. The chances of a conflict are pretty high.

what's your css for the drop down menus look like? Are they jquery or pure css? By the structure looks like jquery.

Theres some stuff I don't like what you're doing there but it won't stop them from working. Anyway I digress..script errors?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely working on one page and not others because your paths are wrong.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

and so on for the other scripts and style references. Note that `src="js` is now `src="/js`. The `/` takes you back to the site root.

Without it, it will look in the current directory for a sub directory named `js`... but since you want the folder at the root of your project named `js`, you need to use `/js`.